# I need to add a range for a date input field in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I've got an input field in a form that needs a date value.  I'm using jQuery UI's datepicker for the calendar and I've set a range for it.  However, the user can override that by typing a different date in the input field.  How can I specify a date range for the field with jQuery validation?  All I see with jQuery is that you can only specify that the field be a date type.  Can I create min and max values that work with dates?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

in responce to comment...

i can imagine many ways of doing this task, such as observing the keypress event, **OR** by checking like this `startDate < myDate && myDate < endDate` **OR** by doing regex etc..!

but the very simple and efficent way is by simply using the `<input/>` [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) property, so by having a sinple input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="dateRange" readonly="readonly" maxlength="10" />
```

you are sure no one can put date, except if they are using the *datepicker*!

that's all! ;-)

---

look like what exactly do **minDate** and **maxDate**

demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/min-max.html

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate: -20, maxDate: '+1M +10D'});
```

> **minDate:** Set a minimum selectable date
> via a Date object or as a string in
> the current dateFormat, or a number of
> days from today (e.g. +7) or a string
> of values and periods ('y' for years,
> 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for
> days, e.g. '-1y -1m'), or null for no
> limit.
>
> - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

---

> **maxDate:** Set a maximum selectable date via a Date object or as a string
> in the current dateFormat, or a number
> of days from today (e.g. +7) or a
> string of values and periods ('y' for
> years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks,
> 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +1w'), or null
> for no limit.
>
> - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Comment: I've got this in my datepicker, but unless I'm doing something wrong, the user has the ability to override that by typing directly in the input field itself.  Thats what I'm trying to set a range on.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a setting to Datepicker to make it so they can't edit the text field:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ constrainInput: true });
```

[jQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-constrainInput)

Comment: That doesn't work.  constrainInput still allows valid characters in the input field.  That means I can change the year.